# Dot product of two HashMaps in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

Suppose there are two HashMaps as follows:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> h1 = [{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3}];
HashMap<String, Integer> h2 = [{"k": 1}, {"f": 4}, {"g":5}, {"a":10}]
```

The multiplication is just like a simple vector multiplication, in this case it will return
**1*10 + 2*0 + 3*0 = 10.**

*That is if the keys are same, then only multiply the two respective values.*

Result -> It should return an **integer**.

Comment: Please share your current attempt to solve it.

Comment: solved below in the answer!

Comment: @ernest_k I couldn't find an approach so I asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int result = 0;
for(String s : h1.keySet()){
    if(h2.containsKey(s)){
        result = result + h2.get(s) * h1.get(s);
    }
}
```